# How to write a systemd script that runs usb_modeswitch and connects to the internet at startup?

Tags: linux, wifi, startup, systemd

I have a cisco AM10 wireless adapter and every boot, I need to run

```
usb_modeswitch -v 1307 -p 1169 -L -I -u -l
```

to get it to function as an adapter. 
Then I have to run a `netcfg` profile to connect to the internet.

I'm very new to systemd, how can I write a startup script that can run these commands, so I won't have to?

Comment: You just put them in a script and reference that in a service file.

Comment: udev might be the other wat to do it... You should be able to run a script if the adapter is plugged in... The data package from here: http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/#download have a udev rules file... (Line 496 in the current one seem to cover your modem / adapter)